# what wrong with mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT person.fornavn, person.etternavn, COUNT(Onske.onr) AS Antall
FROM Person, Onske
WHERE person.pnr = Onske.pnr
ORDER BY Person.fdato;
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: WHile this is a pretty simple question to answer, in general an error message is almost essential...

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `GROUP BY` to do aggregation :

```
SELECT person.fornavn, person.etternavn, COUNT(Onske.onr) AS Antall
FROM Person INNER JOIN
     Onske  
     ON person.pnr = Onske.pnr
GROUP BY person.fornavn, person.etternavn;
```

Also, use always standard *JOIN* syntax instead of comma separate.

Comment: it's worked, thanks

Comment: but if i want (Antall) to show numbers that are bigger then 7 how should i put it?

Comment: @yeye. . . Use `HAVING` clause after `GROUP BY`. `HAVING COUNT(Onske.onr) > 7`.

Comment: ok, but why HAVING and not WHERE?

Comment: @yeye. . . Because you want filter on aggregated data. `Where` will work only with non-aggregated data.

Comment: In other words: `WHERE` applies a condition row-by-row, before the rows are grouped. `HAVING` applies a condition group-by-group. So if you have a condition to eliminate some groups, use `HAVING`.